# Specifying window functions with joins in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I get a syntax error with this SQL command in Postgres, but it seems like it matches the command syntax specified in [the SELECT documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html)

```
select *, 
       row_number() over w 
from units 
   left outer join leases 
window w AS (partition by units.id order by leases.start desc)
```

As far as I can see this matches the syntax which says I can write any SQL statement that is in the form of:

```
SELECT * 
from (table joins) 
WINDOW window_name AS (window_definition)
```

and yet SQL tells me there's an error between `leases` and `window`. What's the error? Why am I misreading the documentation?

Here's the error:

```
2020-03-27 23:02:11.644 PDT [47717] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WINDOW" at character 66
2020-03-27 23:02:11.644 PDT [47717] STATEMENT:  select *, row_number() over w from  units left outer join leases WINDOW w AS (partition by units.id order by leases.start desc)
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WINDOW"
LINE 1: ...umber() over w from  units left outer join leases WINDOW w A...
                                                             ^
```

To clarify my question, I edited it to actually add a window function to the SELECT list, though it's not necessary per the Postgresql SQL spec. At any rate, adding the function doesn't take care of the syntax error; it remains at the same spot.

Comment: You are missing a join condition `left our join leases ON ????`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hwnn has commented your sql is not in error because of your use of WINDOW, it’s because you haven’t put any predicates for the join

```
select *, 
   row_number() over w 
from 
  units u
  left outer join leases l on u.id = l.unitid
  --                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
window w AS (partition by u.id order by l.start desc)
```

If you’re aiming to improve your sql knowledge you might want to skip use of the WINDOW clause because (as far as I’m aware) it’s not supported by all DBMS; learning syntax implemented by only some vendors when a more commonly implemented variant is available is unnecessarily limiting for you

```
select *, 
   row_number() over (partition by u.id order by l.start desc) 
from
  units u
  left outer join leases l on u.id = l.unitid
```

Comment: The `window w AS` is not "vendor specific" it's part of the SQL standard

Comment: Are you happier with my new wording?

Comment: I cannot agree with the second part of the answer. `WINDOW clause` is part of SQL standard and gets a wider addoption over time. The issue is that almost all newer concepts are marked by standard as "optional". But it is not a reason to resign of benefits they introduce.And these "some vendors" are Oracle (20c)/PostgreSQL/MySQL 8.0/SQLite/H2

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?  You are not using any window functions.

So the syntax is simply:

```
select *
from units u left outer join
     leases l 
     on <join conditions here>
```

The `window` clause would be used if you had a window function such as `row_number()` with an `over` clause.

You can add the `window` clause *after* the `from` clause:

```
select *,
       row_number() over w 
from units u left outer join
     leases l 
     on <join conditions here>
window w as (partition by u.id order by l.start desc);
```

It is not needed unless you are going to refer to it more than once, so this is typically used:

```
select *,
       row_number() over (partition by u.id order by l.start desc)
from units u left outer join
     leases l 
     on <join conditions here>;
```

Comment: I edited it to add a window function in the query - it doesn't eliminate the syntax error. At this point, I am merely trying to improve my understanding of SQL.